# Python - Create a List Starting at a Given Value and End at Given Length

Tags: python, list

How can I create a list that will have a starting value and length of the list.  For example, if I wanted to make a list starting at 17 that was of length 5:

```
num_list = [17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
```

I have tried the following however it is not producing the correct results

```
def answer(start, length):
id_arr = list(range(start, length))
print(id_arr)

answer(17, 10)

Output: []
```

And I understand the reason for this because, the starting value, in this case, is 17, however, it is trying to end at value 10 thus creating an empty list so how can I make the value of `length` be the size of the list and not the ending value of the list?

Comment: Could you not initialize an empty list of the necessary length, then fill in your values?

Comment: The constraints of the problem do not allow me to know the size of each list that comes is.  It just states the size will always be at least length 1

Comment: Use  range(start, start + length)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

range function itself does all that for you.

```
range(starting value, endvalue+1, step)
```

so you can go for `range(17,22)`

If you writing custom function then go for:

```
def answer(start, length):
    id_arr = list(range(start, start+length))
    print(id_arr)

answer(17, 5)

output :
[17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
```

Answer (score 3):

in your def

`id_arr = list(range(start, start+length))`

should give you the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Not really, first argument is lower bound and the second is upper bound in terms of half open interval.

```
list(range(10,20))

[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def answer(start, length):
    id_arr = list(range(start, start+length))
    print(id_arr)

answer(17, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

just append to list till range.

```
def answer(start,length):
    anslist=[start]
    for ans in range(length):
        anslist.append(start+ans)
    print anslist
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in range function in Python is very useful to generate sequences of 
numbers in the form of a list. If we provide two parameters in range The first one is starting point, and second one is end point. The given end point is never part of the generated list. So we can use this method:

```
def answer(start, length):
    id_arr = [list_items for list_items in range(start, start + length)]
    print id_arr


answer (17, 5)
>> [17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
```